The difference between std::regex and boost::regex
When there is \r in the matching string, std::regex and boost::regex behave differently. Why?
code:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main()
{ 
    std::string content = "123456728\r,234";
    std::string regex_string = "2.*?4";

    boost::regex reg(regex_string);

    boost::sregex_iterator it(content.begin(),content.end(),reg);
    boost::sregex_iterator end;
    std::cout <<"content size:" << content.size() << std::endl;

    //boost match 234 and 28\r,234
    while (it != end) 
    {
        std::cout <<"boost match: " << it->str(0) <<" size: " <<it->str(0).size() << std::endl;
        ++it;
    }

    std::regex regex_std(regex_string);
    std::sregex_iterator it_std(content.begin(),content.end(),regex_std);
    std::sregex_iterator std_end;

    //std match 234 and 234
    while (it_std != std_end) 
    {
        std::cout <<"std match: " << it_std->str(0) <<" size: " << it_std->str(0).size() << std::endl;
        ++it_std;
    }

    return 0;
}

I think the boost library behaves normally, but I don't understand why the standard library is implemented this way.

historically the standard library's regex has a non-comprehensive and slow implementation and no one can fix it without breaking the API/ABI, which breaks every C++ program, so it can never be fixed, use whatever regex library if you want something fast or good.

Which compiler did you use? There is no monolithic "standard library" that's "implemented this way"; each compiler has its own.

boost::regex is a lot richer than what you get from std::regex. I don't see an issue with adding grammar options to std::regex to support better engines. That shouldn't break backwards compatibility.

@AhmedAEK Like compile time regular expressions ?

relevant Why is std::regex notoriously much slower than other regular expression libraries?, the standard library implementation is not only 10-30 times slow than others, it is also not secure, and you cannot use it in any web server or anything where security is a concern.

@AhmedAEK -- that's the second time you've referred to "the standard library ... implementation". There is no one standard library implementation. Your link refers specifically to libstdc++, so perhaps that's what you're talking about. And, in fact, libstdc++ originally shipped a totally non-functional "implementation" of std::regex which gave many people an unwarranted bad taste for C++ regular expressions. But put the blame where it lies, with that particular implementation, not std::regex itself. And note the answer; the behavior asked about in the question is correct.

That is expected.
std::regex default flavor is ECMAScript-262, and in ECMAScript, the . char matches any character but any LineTerminator character:

The production Atom :: . evaluates as follows:

Let A be the set of all characters except LineTerminator.
Call CharacterSetMatcher(A, false) and return its Matcher result.


And then 7.3Line Terminators says:

Line terminators are included in the set of white space characters that are matched by the \s class in regular expressions.




Code Unit Value
Name
Formal Name




\u000A
Line Feed
<LF>


\u000D
Carriage Return
<CR>


\u2028
Line separator
<LS>


\u2029
Paragraph separator
<PS>



In Boost regex, however, . matches

The NULL character when the flag match_not_dot_null is passed to the matching algorithms.
The newline character when the flag match_not_dot_newline is passed to the matching algorithms.

So, . in Boost regex matches \r, in std::regex, it does not.
